# Kafka (Re-)Joining group stuck with more than 2 topics

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm developing a system that uses Kafka as messaging pub/sub tool.

Data are generated by a scala script:

```
val kafkaParams = new Properties()
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    kafkaParams.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    kafkaParams.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer")
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "test_luca")

    //kafka producer
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaParams)

    //Source list
    val s1 = new java.util.Timer()
    val tasks1 = new java.util.TimerTask {
        def run() = {
            val date = new java.util.Date
            val date2 = date.getTime()
            val send = ""+ date2 + ", 45.1234, 12.5432, 4.5, 3.0"
            val data = new ProducerRecord[String,String]("topic_s1", send)
            producer.send(data)
        }
    }
    s1.schedule(tasks1, 1000L, 1000L)

    val s2 = new java.util.Timer()
    val tasks2 = new java.util.TimerTask {
        def run() = {
            val date = new java.util.Date
            val date2 = date.getTime()
            val send = ""+ date2 + ", 1.111, 9.999, 10.4, 10.0"
            val data = new ProducerRecord[String,String]("topic_s2", send)
            producer.send(data)
        }
    }
    s2.schedule(tasks2, 2000L, 2000L)
```

I need to test the kafka performances in some particular situations. In one case I have an other script that consume data from topics "topic_s1" and "topic_s2", elaborate them and then produce new data with different topics (topic_s1b and topic_s2b). Subsequently these elaborated datum are consumed by an Apache Spark Streaming script.

If I omit the consumer/producer script (I have only 1 Kafka producer with 2 topics and the Spark Script) everything works fine.

If I use the full configuration (1 kafka producer with 2 topics, the "middleware" script that consume data from kafka producer, elaborate them and produce new data with new topics, 1 spark script that consume data with the new topics) the Spark Streaming script is stuck on `INFO AbstractCoordinator: (Re-)joining group test_luca`

I'm running everything locally and I do not make modifications to the kafka and zookeeper configurations.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE: The spark script:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkScript").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true").setMaster("local[2]")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(4))

case class Thema(name: String, metadata: JObject)
case class Tempo(unit: String, count: Int, metadata: JObject)
case class Spatio(unit: String, metadata: JObject)
case class Stt(spatial: Spatio, temporal: Tempo, thematic: Thema)
case class Location(latitude: Double, longitude: Double, name: String)

case class Data(location: Location, timestamp: Long, measurement: Int, unit: String, accuracy: Double)
case class Sensor(sensor_name: String, start_date: String, end_date: String, data_schema: Array[String], data: Data, stt: Stt)


case class Datas(location: Location, timestamp: Long, measurement: Int, unit: String, accuracy: Double)
case class Sensor2(sensor_name: String, start_date: String, end_date: String, data_schema: Array[String], data: Datas, stt: Stt)


val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer].getCanonicalName,
    "group.id" -> "test_luca",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
    "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
)

val topics1 = Array("topics1")
val topics2 = Array("topics2")

val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics1, kafkaParams))
val stream2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String](topics2, kafkaParams))

val s1 = stream.map(record => {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  parse(record.value).extract[Sensor]
}
)
val s2 = stream2.map(record => {
  implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
  parse(record.value).extract[Sensor2]
}
)

val f1 = s1.map { x => x.sensor_name }
f1.print()
val f2 = s2.map { x => x.sensor_name }
f2.print()
```

Thanks
Luca

Comment: please show your spark streaming script code.

Comment: @GuangshengZuo I've uploaded the Spark Script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should change the group.id for spark streaming script. I guess your "middleware" script's consumer has the same group.id as your spark streaming script's consumer. Then the terrible thing will happen.

In kafka, the consumer group is a real subscriber for topic, the consumer in a group is just a splitting worker, so in your case, you should use different group.id in middleware script consumer and spark streaming script consumer.

In your first try which do not have the middle script, it works just because this.